# PHP format of date from Oracle database

Tags: php, oracle

I store date in the database under `CREATED` using `select sysdate from dual` and it will store the value `9/12/2012 9:26:05 AM` Which is exactly what I want.

However, when I retrieve the information with PHP (e.g `$query[0]['CREATED']`) it returns `12-SEP-12`

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you retrieve a date, it has to converted from an abstract representation of a point-in-time to a string of characters. If you don't specify a format, it will use one by default (usually `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`):

```
SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
---------
12-SEP-12
```

If you want a specific format, you have to use a conversion function, such as [`TO_CHAR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions200.htm#i1009324):

```
SQL> SELECT to_char(sysdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss am') dt FROM DUAL;

DT
----------------------
12/09/2012 04:25:04 pm
```

Answer (score 5):

Just for completeness, you can have your connection set up at the beginning so from that moment the dates are always retrieved in a particular format, like this:

```
// Typical connection boilerplate
$conn_string = $config['engine'] . ':host=' . $config['host'] . ';port=' . $config['port'] . ';dbname=' . $config['dbname'] . ';charset=utf8';

$db = new PDO($conn_string,
    $config['username'],
    $config['password']
);

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// This is where you prepare your session
// For your case, the format should be 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss am' as stated on the previous answers
$db->query("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'");
```

That way you can perform general `SELECT *`'s without worrying every time about the format for a particular `DATE` column.

Answer (score 0):

Convert with sysdate and type with DD-MM-YYYY will return `12-09-2012`:

```
select field name, TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS sysdate from database name;
```